# Pymysql error with syntax and I don't understand

Tags: python, mysql, bots, discord, discord.py

I trying to add users in to database but stuck with this error:

```
[08/Oct/2018 14:18:01] - [O M N I A] Updated online for user: Майор пейн
[08/Oct/2018 14:18:01] - [O M N I A] Updated online for user: Nikodus
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/root/bot/botevents.py", line 48, in counter
db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`server_id`, `user_name`, `user_id`, `last_update_online`, `last_update`) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', {3}, {3})".format(server.id, member.name.replace("'", ''), member.id, time.time()))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
result = self._query(query)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
conn.query(q)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 727, in _read_query_result
result.read()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1066, in read
first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
packet.check_error()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '397911167944622100', 1539008281.6296663, 1539008281.6296663)' at line 1")
```

It's add some users but in one moment stuck and get that error.
It's possible bcz it's a 7k users and I have a VDS with only one core and 2 ram?

```
import pymysql, time, discord
from datetime import datetime

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

class BotEvents:

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    @self.bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        self.log('\n', save=True)
        self.log('-----------------------------------------', save=True)
        self.log('Authorize successfully', save=True)
        self.log('Authorized servers: ', save=True)
        [self.log('  Name (id): %s (%s)' % (info.name, info.id), save=True) for info in self.bot.guilds]
        self.log('-----------------------------------------', save=True)

        await self.bot.loop.create_task(self.female_logic())


def counter(self, server):
    db_conn, db_cursor = self.connect_db()
    result = db_cursor.execute("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE server_id = '{}'".format(server.id))
    members = []
    if result != 0:
        for x in range(result):
            members.append(db_cursor.fetchone()[0])
    db_conn.close()
    while self.run_c:
        roles = []
        member_role = []
        db_conn, db_cursor = self.connect_db()
        result = db_cursor.execute("SELECT `role_id`, `min_exp` FROM `auto_roles` WHERE server_id = '{}' ORDER BY `min_exp`".format(server.id))
        if result != 0:
            info = db_cursor.fetchone()
            member_role = [str(info[0]), int(info[1])]
            for x in range(result - 1):
                info = db_cursor.fetchone()
                roles.append([str(info[0]), int(info[1])])
        db_conn.close()

        for member in server.members:
            if member != self.bot.user:
                db_conn, db_cursor = self.connect_db()
                if str(member.id) not in members:
                    db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`server_id`, `user_name`, `user_id`, `last_update_online`, `last_update`) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', {3}, {3})".format(server.id, member.name.replace("'", ''), member.id, time.time()))
                    db_conn.commit()
                    members.append(str(member.id))
                    self.log(' [%s] Added user: %s' % (server.name, member.name), save=True)
                else:
                    db_cursor.execute("SELECT `member`, `balance`, `online_time`, `last_update_online`, `experience`, `last_update`, `autorole` FROM `users` WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(member.id, server.id))
                    info = db_cursor.fetchone()
                    if info is not None:
                        info = {
                            'member':bool(info[0]),
                            'balance':int(info[1]),
                            'online_time':int(info[2]),
                            'last_update_online':int(info[3]),
                            'experience':int(info[4]),
                            'last_update':int(info[5]),
                            'autorole':info[6]
                            }

                        if int(time.time()) - info['last_update_online'] > 60:
                            if str(member.status) in ['online', 'idle', 'dnd']:
                                db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET online_time = {}, last_update_online = {} WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(
                                                                                                                info['online_time'] + 1,
                                                                                                                time.time(),
                                                                                                                member.id,
                                                                                                                server.id))
                                db_conn.commit()
                                self.log('[%s] Updated online for user: %s ' % (server.name, member.name), save=True)


                        if int(time.time()) - info['last_update'] > 60:
                            if member.voice is not None:
                                db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET balance = {}, experience = {}, last_update = {} WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(
                                                                                                                        info['balance'] + self.gold_per_minut, 
                                                                                                                        info['experience'] + self.exp_per_minut,
                                                                                                                        time.time(),
                                                                                                                        member.id,
                                                                                                                        server.id))
                                db_conn.commit()
                                self.log('[%s] Updated balance, experience for user: %s ' % (server.name, member.name), save=True)


                        if len(member_role) != 0:
                            if not info['member'] and info['experience'] >= member_role[1]:
                                role_o = discord.utils.get(server.roles, id=int(member_role[0]))
                                if role_o not in member.roles:
                                    self.bot.loop.create_task(member.add_roles(role_o))
                                    db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET member = {} WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(True, member.id, server.id))
                                    db_conn.commit()

                            new_role = ''
                            for role in roles:
                                if role[1] <= info['experience']:
                                    new_role = role[0]

                            if new_role != '' and new_role != info['autorole']:
                                if info['autorole'] != '0':
                                    role_o = discord.utils.get(server.roles, id=int(info['autorole']))
                                    if role_o in member.roles:
                                        self.bot.loop.create_task(member.remove_roles(role_o))
                                        self.log('[%s] For user %s deleted old role %s(%s)' % (
                                                                                server.name, 
                                                                                member.name, 
                                                                                role_o.name, 
                                                                                role_o.id) , save=True)

                                        time.sleep(2)

                                role_o = discord.utils.get(server.roles, id=int(new_role))
                                if role_o is not None:
                                    if role_o not in member.roles:
                                        db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET autorole = '{}' WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(new_role, member.id, server.id))
                                        db_conn.commit()
                                        self.bot.loop.create_task(member.add_roles(role_o))
                                        self.log('[%s] For user %s added role %s(%s)' % (server.name, member.name, role_o.name, role_o.id), save=True)
                db_conn.close()
```

Someone knew how to fix this?
botevents.py file which get this error ([pastebin snippet](https://pastebin.com/UdMhDrMh))

@Suresh, complete error after add quote:

```
[08/Oct/2018 16:37:33] -  [O M N I A] Added user: Shein
[08/Oct/2018 16:37:33] -  [O M N I A] Added user: ара
[08/Oct/2018 16:37:34] -  [O M N I A] Added user: ROFLANOV
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/root/bot/botevents.py", line 48, in counter
db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`server_id`, `user_name`, `user_id`, `last_update_online`, `last_update`) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{3}')".format(server.id, member.name.replace("'", ''), member.id, time.time()))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
result = self._query(query)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
conn.query(q)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 727, in _read_query_result
result.read()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1066, in read
first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
packet.check_error()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '397911167944622100', '1539016654.7659388', '1539016654.7659388')' at line 1")
```

Comment: Add your error as text here rather than an external link.

Comment: i fixed with code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose time values in single quote while inserting data.
Please use code below:

```
import pymysql, time, discord
from datetime import datetime

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

class BotEvents:

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    @self.bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        self.log('\n', save=True)
        self.log('-----------------------------------------', save=True)
        self.log('Authorize successfully', save=True)
        self.log('Authorized servers: ', save=True)
        [self.log('  Name (id): %s (%s)' % (info.name, info.id), save=True) for info in self.bot.guilds]
        self.log('-----------------------------------------', save=True)

        await self.bot.loop.create_task(self.female_logic())


def counter(self, server):
    db_conn, db_cursor = self.connect_db()
    result = db_cursor.execute("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE server_id = '{}'".format(server.id))
    members = []
    if result != 0:
        for x in range(result):
            members.append(db_cursor.fetchone()[0])
    db_conn.close()
    while self.run_c:
        roles = []
        member_role = []
        db_conn, db_cursor = self.connect_db()
        result = db_cursor.execute("SELECT `role_id`, `min_exp` FROM `auto_roles` WHERE server_id = '{}' ORDER BY `min_exp`".format(server.id))
        if result != 0:
            info = db_cursor.fetchone()
            member_role = [str(info[0]), int(info[1])]
            for x in range(result - 1):
                info = db_cursor.fetchone()
                roles.append([str(info[0]), int(info[1])])
        db_conn.close()

        for member in server.members:
            if member != self.bot.user:
                db_conn, db_cursor = self.connect_db()
                if str(member.id) not in members:
                    db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`server_id`, `user_name`, `user_id`, `last_update_online`, `last_update`) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{3}')".format(server.id, member.name.replace("'", ''), member.id, time.time()))
                    db_conn.commit()
                    members.append(str(member.id))
                    self.log(' [%s] Added user: %s' % (server.name, member.name), save=True)
                else:
                    db_cursor.execute("SELECT `member`, `balance`, `online_time`, `last_update_online`, `experience`, `last_update`, `autorole` FROM `users` WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(member.id, server.id))
                    info = db_cursor.fetchone()
                    if info is not None:
                        info = {
                            'member':bool(info[0]),
                            'balance':int(info[1]),
                            'online_time':int(info[2]),
                            'last_update_online':int(info[3]),
                            'experience':int(info[4]),
                            'last_update':int(info[5]),
                            'autorole':info[6]
                            }

                        if int(time.time()) - info['last_update_online'] > 60:
                            if str(member.status) in ['online', 'idle', 'dnd']:
                                db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET online_time = {}, last_update_online = {} WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(
                                                                                                                info['online_time'] + 1,
                                                                                                                time.time(),
                                                                                                                member.id,
                                                                                                                server.id))
                                db_conn.commit()
                                self.log('[%s] Updated online for user: %s ' % (server.name, member.name), save=True)


                        if int(time.time()) - info['last_update'] > 60:
                            if member.voice is not None:
                                db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET balance = {}, experience = {}, last_update = {} WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(
                                                                                                                        info['balance'] + self.gold_per_minut, 
                                                                                                                        info['experience'] + self.exp_per_minut,
                                                                                                                        time.time(),
                                                                                                                        member.id,
                                                                                                                        server.id))
                                db_conn.commit()
                                self.log('[%s] Updated balance, experience for user: %s ' % (server.name, member.name), save=True)


                        if len(member_role) != 0:
                            if not info['member'] and info['experience'] >= member_role[1]:
                                role_o = discord.utils.get(server.roles, id=int(member_role[0]))
                                if role_o not in member.roles:
                                    self.bot.loop.create_task(member.add_roles(role_o))
                                    db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET member = {} WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(True, member.id, server.id))
                                    db_conn.commit()

                            new_role = ''
                            for role in roles:
                                if role[1] <= info['experience']:
                                    new_role = role[0]

                            if new_role != '' and new_role != info['autorole']:
                                if info['autorole'] != '0':
                                    role_o = discord.utils.get(server.roles, id=int(info['autorole']))
                                    if role_o in member.roles:
                                        self.bot.loop.create_task(member.remove_roles(role_o))
                                        self.log('[%s] For user %s deleted old role %s(%s)' % (
                                                                                server.name, 
                                                                                member.name, 
                                                                                role_o.name, 
                                                                                role_o.id) , save=True)

                                        time.sleep(2)

                                role_o = discord.utils.get(server.roles, id=int(new_role))
                                if role_o is not None:
                                    if role_o not in member.roles:
                                        db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET autorole = '{}' WHERE (user_id = '{}' AND server_id = '{}')".format(new_role, member.id, server.id))
                                        db_conn.commit()
                                        self.bot.loop.create_task(member.add_roles(role_o))
                                        self.log('[%s] For user %s added role %s(%s)' % (server.name, member.name, role_o.name, role_o.id), save=True)
                db_conn.close()
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from botevents import BotEvents
  File "/root/bot/botevents.py", line 9
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      ^
i get this error with your code.

Comment: I have updated  '{3}', '{3}' in your code instead of {3},{3} . please check with the same changes.

Comment: not worked. added 1740 users and errored again with same error.

Comment: same but with quote: ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{3}')"

Comment: i posted above(not adapted with this site).

Comment: Only use member.name variable in your insert query.